# JS script is not included in Django project

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm learning django and have a problem. JS script is not included in Django project. The path is correct, the page itself with the graph block works, but the output of a round or bar chart does not occur.

```
index.html
```

```
{% extends 'partials/base.html' %}
{% block title %}Home Page{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-6 my-4">
        <div class="bg-white">
            <div class="card-body">
                <canvas id="myChart1" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
                <script src="{% static 'main.js' %}"></script>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 my-4">
        <div class="bg-white">
            <div class="card-body">
                <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
                <script>
                    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
                    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                        type: 'bar',
                        data: {
                            labels: [{% for order in order %} '{{order.name}}',{% endfor %}],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Orders',
                        data: [{% for order in order %} {{ order.order_quantity }}, {% endfor %}],
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                        ],
                            borderColor: [
                                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                            ],
                                borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                        },
                    options: {
                        scales: {
                            yAxes: [{
                                ticks: {
                                    beginAtZero: true
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                    });
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

```
base.html
```

```
<!--Chartjs CDN-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.4/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <!--Custome CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <title>{% block title %} {% endblock %}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {% include 'partials/nav.html' %}

    {% include 'partials/topnav.html' %}
     <div class="container">

        {% block content %}

        {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->
```

```
settings.py
```

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = (BASE_DIR/"media/")

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]
```

I tried to translate the js script into a separate file, but it didn’t work. How can you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to run `python3 manage.py collectstatic` for Django to collect your files for the project.

Comment: Thank you! After another launch an error occurred, I corrected the code in the code:
` STATIC_URL = 'static/' `
` STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / STATIC_URL `